# Are all variations of Unown in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

One of the more unique Pokémon that exists in Generation II is [Unown](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Unown_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), which contains 26 variations that correspond with the 26 letters in the Latin Alphabet; 28 including ? and ! released in Generation III

[image]

Now that Generation II has been released in Pokémon Go, can we expect to see all 26 variations of Unown, or are there specific ones that are available?

Comment: [This article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/02/has-unown-been-found-in-pokemon-go-photos-where-cp-stats-when-screenshots-pics/) shows some different variation of Unown through in-game screenshots, so its possible. Side note: Could of swore Unown (as in the Pokemon name) was still spelled "Unknown."  I never picked up on this as a kid...

Comment: @TimmyJim If it makes you feel better, I had the realization myself while asking this question. I feel like my entire childhood has been a lie

Comment: @TimmyJim Since we're talking about spelling realizations, it's "could have sworn"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The 26 variations are available !**

Once you catch one Unown a new badge appears (called Unown) and the gold medal requires you to catch 26 Unown :

[image]

*(However I don't know if they need to be different or if the same letter still counts as progress in the badge.)*

Here is a list of all the 26 Unown variations I found on the web :

- A : [image: Unown A] - source : [kotaku.com](http://kotaku.com/why-pokemon-go-players-are-so-hyped-about-unown-1792514148)
- B : [image: Unown B] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)
- C : [image: Unown C] - source : [kotaku.com](http://kotaku.com/why-pokemon-go-players-are-so-hyped-about-unown-1792514148)
- D : [image: Unown D] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)
- E : [image: Unown E] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)
- F : [image: Unown F] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/mReG7ZmSp0Q)
- G : [image: Unown G] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/rjHGotlhzi0)
- H : [image: Unown H] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)
- I : [image: Unown I] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/uyI234HmvAk)
- J : [image: Unown J] - source [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5wamgd/the_silph_road_alphabet_of_unown/)
- K : [image: Unown K] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)
- L : [image: Unown L] - source : [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1461668170532401&set=pcb.1870576279855536&type=3)
- M : [image: Unown M] - source : [twitter post](https://twitter.com/Cosmoesis/status/833159539398627328/photo/1)
- N : [image: Unown N] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)
- O : [image: Unown O] - source : [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/5ul8d8/i_caught_an_unown_information_inside_usa_theyre/)
- P : [image: Unown P] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/rjHGotlhzi0)
- Q - [image: Unown Q] - source [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5wamgd/the_silph_road_alphabet_of_unown/)
- R : [image: Unown R] - source : [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSAJ-w8XV5U)
- S : [image: Unown S] - source : [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TUqZHeEFXQ)
- T : [image: Unown T] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/rjHGotlhzi0)
- U : [image: Unown U] - source : [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/5ul8d8/i_caught_an_unown_information_inside_usa_theyre/de1yu3m/)
- V : [image: Unown V] - source : [Picture on facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1364060030284098&set=pcb.1364060116950756&type=3)
- W : [image: Unown W] - source : [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fHKOksXtAg)
- X : [image: Unown X] - source [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5wamgd/the_silph_road_alphabet_of_unown/)
- Y : [image: Unown Y] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)
- Z : [image: unown Z] - source : [youtube video](https://youtu.be/RmAWdvmsSeQ)

EDIT :
[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5wamgd/the_silph_road_alphabet_of_unown/) is also referencing all the unown variations

Comment: Great job on finding all of these!